# Div not moving when I resized window

Tags: html

I have a div with an absolute position of 425 px from the top. When I resize the window all other dives move/resize but this one does not. It can be seen at http://www.billtsellshomes.com . It is working fine for mobile devises but I have this problem on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to your whiteout div, the styles are being overwritten.  If you inspect it you can see the css is crossed out.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where this is happening.